# Continue most recent value over a time range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this existing schema where a "schedule" table looks like this (very simplified).

```
CREATE TABLE schedule (
  id           int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name         varchar(45),
  start_date   date,
  availability int(3),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

For each person it specifies a start date and percentage of work time available to spent on this project. That availability percentage *implicitly continues* until a newer value is specified.
For example take a project that lasts from 2012-02-27 to 2012-03-02:

```
id | name | start_date | availability
-------------------------------------
 1 |  Tom | 2012-02-27 |          100 
 2 |  Tom | 2012-02-29 |           50
 3 |  Ben | 2012-03-01 |           80
```

So Tom starts on Feb., 27nd, full time, until Feb, 29th, from which on he'll be available only with 50% of his work time.
Ben only starts on March, 1st and only with 80% of his time.

Now the goal is to "normalize" this sparse data, so that there is a result row for each person for each day with the availability coming from the last specified day:

```
name | start_date | availability
--------------------------------
 Tom | 2012-02-27 |          100 
 Tom | 2012-02-28 |          100
 Tom | 2012-02-29 |           50
 Tom | 2012-03-01 |           50
 Tom | 2012-03-02 |           50
 Ben | 2012-02-27 |            0 
 Ben | 2012-02-28 |            0
 Ben | 2012-02-29 |            0
 Ben | 2012-03-01 |           80
 Ben | 2012-03-02 |           80
```

Think a chart showing the availability of each person over time, or calculating the "resource" values in a burndown diagram.
I can easily do this with procedural code in the app layer, but would prefer a nicer, faster solution.

Comment: Going procedural may be more optimal depending on how the data is being used as there's no rows for the missing dates.

Comment: In your original data I don't see the date 2012-03-02 anywhere. Where does it come from, how is the end of the project determined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this remotely effective, I recommend creating a `calendar` table.  One that contains each and every date of interest.  You then use that as a template on which to join your data.

Equally, things improve further if you have `person` table to act as the template for the name dimension of your results.

You can then use a correlated sub-query in your join, to pick which record in `Schedule` matches the `calendar`, `person` template you have created.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  calendar
CROSS JOIN
  person
LEFT JOIN
  schedule
    ON  schedule.name       = person.name
    AND schedule.start_date = (SELECT MAX(start_date)
                                 FROM schedule
                                WHERE name = person.name
                                  AND start_date <= calendar.date)
WHERE
      calendar.date >= <yourStartDate>
  AND calendar.date <= <yourEndDate>
  etc
```

Often, however, it is more efficient to deal with it in one of two other ways...

Don't allow gaps in the data in the first place.  Have a nightly batch process, or some other business logic that ensures all relevant dat apoints are populated.

Or deal with it in your client.  Return each dimension in you report (data, and name) as seperate data sets to act as your templates, and then return the data as your final data set.  Your client can itterate over the data and fill in the blanks as appropriate.  It's more code, but can actually use less resource overall than trying to fill-the-gaps with SQL.

*(If your client side code does this slowly, post another question examining that code.  Provided that the data is sorted, this is acutally quite quick to do in most languages.)*

Comment: "If your client code does this slowly" => Well, that isn't really the problem. The main problem is that if I calculate the values in the app layer, then I must do *all* subsequent computations in the client layer, too - like summing up for a total. That totally feels like it belongs in the DB (iterating over values and running up a total).

Comment: @StephenFriedrich - Where the calendar date pre-dates any record for a user, the Schedule record will be NULL.  In such cases you can use `COALESCE(availability, 0)` to turn the NULL to a 0.  If you are getting NULLS for dates where a preceding data record does exist, something is wrong and I'd need an example of the code you implemented to be able to investigate.

Comment: Sorry that problem I mentioned was an error in data setup. Serves me right for not including complete scripts, including insert statements. Thanks for the solution! It is even easy to add a flag to indicate if the value is explicit or implied (shown in gray in the UI): if(calendar.date = schedule.start_date, 1, 0) as explicit